# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: in iOS Today Widget with UITableViewController called once

Tags: uitableview, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I'm trying to display data in Today Widget extension in UIViewController subclass. The number of items (rows) is alway *3* but the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called only once.

I've double-checked everything but cannot find a bug.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"

#import "FLWAccount.h"
#import "FLWAccountTableViewCell.h"
#import "FLWAuthManager.h"

#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet UITableView
*tableView;

@end

@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 79.0f;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 79.0f;

    [self updatePreferredContentSize];
    [self.tableView reloadData];}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    [[FLWAuthManager sharedManager] updateAllAccountsWithCompletion:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updatePreferredContentSize];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
        });
    }]; }

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger count = [FLWAuthManager sharedManager].accounts.count;
    return count; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FLWAccountTableViewCell *cell = (FLWAccountTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FLWAccountTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.account = [FLWAuthManager sharedManager].accounts[indexPath.row];
    return cell; }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 79.0f; }

- (void)updatePreferredContentSize {
    NSInteger count = [FLWAuthManager sharedManager].accounts.count;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.preferredContentSize.width, 79.0f * count); }

@end
```

Comment: If `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is only called once, that's telling you that the number of items is not actually 3. Have you verified that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns 3?

Comment: I checked it, it's for sure 3. In `updatePreferredContentSize` I'm setting the size of the widget and there it is 3 too and the size of the widget is three times more than the only displayed cell

Comment: Is `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` getting called? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes it is called. I can add NSLogs and paste here the output

Comment: Yes, please. And log the count in `updatePreferedContnetSize`

Comment: I have a suggestion. Don't use self in a block. use a weak self for this one.

Comment: 2 other rows may be considered not visible (not currently present on display) and then cellForRowAtIndexPath wouldn't be called for them. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboard, check if the table view content is set to "Dynamic Prototypes" (and NOT "Static cells")

[image]

Comment: I've just checked and it's **Dynamic Prototypes**